# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: visitor.messages is undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I have a parent table in laravel, I am able to access the data of its child in vuejs i.e
the parent table visits and its child is messages so to access the messages for each visit, first I am looping through the visits and each visit accessing the messages.

Since it's a real-time app (i am using laravel echo and laravel WebSockets), I want when someone else on the system sends a message, the received message to be pushed to the already existing array.

This is the code that's supposed to push incoming messages

```
this.visitors.push(event['message'])
```

if I console

```
console.log(event['message'].message)
```

I am getting the exact message I have sent. This is the error I am getting

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render:  "TypeError: visitor.messages is undefined".
```

Comment: So where does the `this.visitors` value come from? A parent blade file?

Comment: you are using `messages` instead of `message`. may be its an issue.

Comment: a visitor has messages that's why I am using messages instead of message